# How to anchor UIView a few pixel off the middle point using Autoresizing Mask?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

Observe the following screenshot:

[image: iPhone Autoresizing Mask Question]

How do I anchor UIView a few pixel off the middle point using Autoresizing Mask so that it is always 20px to the left of the middle point?

I have tried setting the `autoresizingMask` property to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin` and it's not really doing it.

I did manage to do it if I wrap the view in another bigger view that fills the entire screen and doesn't resize at all. But is there a way to do it without an additional view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autoresizing masks don't handle this case very well, as you've already discovered. They work great if you want to keep something a fixed distance from its superview or proportionally resizing/repositioning somewhere in the middle. You can do a surprising amount with just those options, but off-center anchoring is not something you can do easily

If you want do this with autoresizing masks, you'll need to put your box inside another empty `UIView`, one that is in a more convenient position for autoresizing masks. It will look like this.

Here's what you've got right now:

```
                       center
                          |
|---------------------------------------------------|  <-- The main parent view
               |-----|  <-- your view
```

What you want is this:

```
                       center
                          |
|---------------------------------------------------|  <-- The main parent view
               |--------------------|  <-- The new view, centered in the parent
               |-----|  <-- your view
```

The new view should be completely transparent, have a fixed width, and a flexible distance from both sides of the parent view. It should be wide enough to fully contain the off-center box, and no wider. If it is positioned exactly in the center of the main parent view, it will stay centered no matter what happens to the size of the parent view.

Then add your box as a subview of the new view, with a fixed width and fixed distance from the left edge of the parent. Now, using only autoresizing masks, your view will stay where you want it.

A simpler option might be to override `-layoutSubviews` on your view, or `-viewDidLayoutSubviews` on your controller (available iOS 5.0 and later) and just manually position the view. But you asked how to do it with autoresizing masks, so that's what you got.  Without adding an extra view, there's no way to use autoresizing masks to get the positioning behavior you want.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation. I decided to go with extra view implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the best solution is to set center property to:

myview.center = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2-20, myview.center.y);

And set up it  in willRotate method.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not sure if that's cleaner than just having Autoresizing Mask handle it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly an answer, more of an avenue for exploration. You can try playing with the layer-level property anchorPoint. Setting it to (1.0, 0.5) means the layer's position will be defined by its right edge. In that case centered would mean the right edge is centered. Set flexible left margin and flexible right margin and it might stay left of the center.

To get it exactly 20p left of the center, just set the anchorPoint to 20p right of the center of the view. (But anchorPoint units are a fraction of the size of the layer, so do some math to find the right value.)

I'm not sure if it will work. I'm not sure what the effects are of mixing layer-level positioning with autoresizing.